# Build Group chat using socket io in Android

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I want to create a Group chat application based on Android and socket.io functionality just like Whatsapp.

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow, but it looks like you received some fairly full answers anyway, and then failed to respond to them? It appears you have asked several questions since.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I don't really understand the question, but here is a very small simple chat room I wrote with socket.io a couple of years ago.  I hope you can use it as a skeleton..

```
<body><ul id="Messages"></ul>
<form action="">
    <input id="Message" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="button" id="Send" value="Send">
</form>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $.getScript('socket.io/socket.io.js', function () {
        initSocket();
    });

    var initSocket = function () {
        var socket = io();

        $('#Send').click(function () {
        var userNameTag = $('#UserNameTag');
        var nameTag = userNameTag.html();
        if (nameTag) {
            socket.emit('ioChatMessage', { text: nameTag + ':  ' + $('#Message').val(), style: userNameTag[0].style });
        } else {
            socket.emit('ioChatMessage', { text: $('#Message').val() });
        }

        $('#Message').val('');
        return false;
    });

    socket.on('ioChatMessage', function (msg) {
        $('#Messages').append($('<li>').text(msg.text).css(msg.style));
    });

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        socket.disconnect();
    };
};
    </script>
</body>
```

App.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

socket.on('connection', function (io) {
    io.on('ioChatMessage', function (msg) {
        socket.emit('ioChatMessage', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: this is of course assuming that you already have the node / webserver setup

Answer (score 1):

In this page you can learn how to build a chat group using socket.io in a browser:

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

My recomendation if you want it to be an Android app is to do it like you see in the tutorial and then use Apache Cordova to make it an Android App anyone can install.

You can download it from here:

https://cordova.apache.org/

The final index.html should look like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```